# What are these random-named DLLs in my Visual Studio Installer project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

Noticed recently that my Visual Studio 2017 Setup and Deployment project is packaging a bunch of DLLs with seemingly random names such as "9f013frf.dll". The DLLs don't seem to exist in the build folders, nor do they appear in the installation target folder after install. Not sure when this started happening.

This installer project is used to deploy about a dozen different project outputs, which are a mixture of DB, .NET, and native C++ projects.

[image: screen cap of build output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those file names are typically the ones you find in the C++ merge modules, so I assume you have them in your project. Merge modules are merged into the MSI file so you'll see these messages.